# Using uniqueidentifier SQL column type with Entity framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-4.0

For my primary key and identity in our Clients table I use `uniqueidentifier` column with a default value set to newsequentialid(). Inserting new rows through the management tool creates the values for the ID fine.

Inserting from .NET 4 code via EF results into zero GUIDs (00000-0000....) being inserted. I create the entity with new, set some values and perform EF `AddToClients` (for instance). If debugged, value for the id property shows zero GUID. I do not explicitly set the id via the `Guid.NewGuid()` in my code because I want to leave it off to the `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server. The problem is, it doesn't work. The first time the code is executed row gets inserted with zero GUID. The next time it obviously fails and results in primary key violation exception.

How can I get this to work without having to set the GUID in my client code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the `StoreGeneratedPattern` value for the property in the EF designer. Set it to `Identity`. This will cause EF to avoid setting the value on an insert, then capture it after the insert is complete.

Note that if you're using EF 4, you may have trouble with this using the designer only (see [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6b00ae43-01d2-4939-943e-fc47aeec5c2a)). You may have to edit the .edmx manually and set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` in the storage model itself.

Comment: Did it. No change. The entity still has ZERO GUID set prior to insertion and insertion fails with duplicate key (I left the previously inserted one in the table).

Comment: ohh i see about the designer issues...this is just great..ON top of other issue I wrote about in another question, now this. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @mare: I feel your pain. EF is a powerful tool, but when you encounter something that it doesn't handle *well*, it can be an enormous headache to get around it.

Comment: enormous is certainly the right word because this is a major pain in the ..., just reading this http://geeksharp.com/2010/05/27/ef4-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-ssdl/

Comment: @AdamRobinson Many Thanks for your answer. I was facing the same problem and it solved it with no time.

Comment: @AdamRobinson, whenever I update the property of my column StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity", and then run the program and do dbContext.SaveChanges(), I get the following error: =====> store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. refresh objectstatemanager entries.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. It's a real pain. Here's one page about it, w/ comments from Microsoft - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/aecf14e3-e4c9-439b-88af-23d4353afb9d.

My workaround was to create a stored procedure to use for the INSERT. This page has some info on how to do that - http://thedatafarm.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/. So far I only have an insert stored proc - nothing for update or delete; and contrary to the article, I'm not getting a model validation error.

*CORRECTION* EF let me get as far as retrieving a list of entities, but when I went to get an instance of a specific one, I got the error about missing a mapping function for updates. Ugh!

To retrieve the inserted UUID that was generated with newsequentialid(), I used the "OUTPUT INSERTED.[column]" technique that was introduced with SQL Server 2005. An example is at [Retrieve last row inserted with Uniqueidentifier that it is not IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457636/retrieve-last-row-inserted-with-uniqueidentifier-that-it-is-not-identity). I used the same technique in the INSERT stored procedure to retrieve datetime columns that were set with a default getdate().

Hope this helps someone,

Donnie

Comment: for a workaround I used the Guid.NewGuid() function in my code, so I just generate a GUID for my new entities prior to inserting. It is not sequential but it works and it will continue to work when EF changes in future versions. The performance impact should be low on tables with a few hundred records.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in you .edmx. Open with XML text editor with encoding or another.
Find the id name and add the attribute beside it in same tag: StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity".

Example:

< Property Name="WorkerId" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />